# How to serialize gtk.TextBuffer containing a TextChildAnchor

Tags: python, textview, pygtk

I cannot serialize a TextBuffer that contains anchors. I was hoping to serialize text to each anchor, skip the anchor and repeat. But the presence of an anchor in the buffer prevents serialization even if anchor is not in the serialization range. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Alternatively, if I delete the anchor it works. Is there a way to create a copy of the TextBuffer? using copy.copy I get "TypeError: gobject.GObject descendants' instances are non-copyable"

Here is a working test code:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(300, 300)
window.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

vb = gtk.VBox()
window.add(vb)

tv1 = gtk.TextView()
tb1 = tv1.get_buffer()
vb.pack_start(tv1)

def on_bt1_clicked(button, ):
    """ Case1: We delete anchor... it is possible to serialize buffer range."""
    serialFormat = tb1.register_serialize_tagset()
    print("Button 1 was clicked")

    iter_at_anchor = tb1.get_iter_at_child_anchor(anchor1)
    iter_at_anchor.forward_char()
    tb1.backspace(iter=iter_at_anchor, interactive=True, default_editable=True)

    tb1.serialize(tb1, serialFormat, tb1.get_start_iter(), iter_at_anchor)
    print("serialize was sucessful")

bt1 = gtk.Button("click me 1")
bt1.connect("clicked", on_bt1_clicked)
txt = "Some not so random text."
iter=tb1.get_start_iter()
tb1.insert(iter=iter, text=txt)
iter.set_offset(char_offset=10)
anchor1 = tb1.create_child_anchor(iter)
tv1.add_child_at_anchor(bt1, anchor1)


tv2 = gtk.TextView()
tb2 = tv2.get_buffer()
vb.pack_start(tv2)

def on_bt2_clicked(button, ):
    """ Case2: We leave anchor but don't include it in range to be 
        serialized... it is not possible to serialize buffer range as process
        freezes."""
    serialFormat = tb2.register_serialize_tagset()
    print("Button 2 was clicked")

    iter_at_anchor = tb2.get_iter_at_child_anchor(anchor2)
    iter_at_anchor.backward_char()

    tb2.serialize(tb2, serialFormat, tb2.get_start_iter(), iter_at_anchor)
    print("serialize was sucessful") # does not reach here

bt2 = gtk.Button("click me 2")
bt2.connect("clicked", on_bt2_clicked)
txt = "Some not so random text."
iter=tb2.get_start_iter()
tb2.insert(iter=iter, text=txt)
iter.set_offset(char_offset=10)
anchor2 = tb2.create_child_anchor(iter)
tv2.add_child_at_anchor(bt2, anchor2)

window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

thanks for any input